# cmake how to include shaders.qrc

Tags: qt, cmake

So, I'm making a program with a shaders.qrc. I'm using only Qt and Cmake. I know that I can do Resources += shaders.qrc in qmake but I don't know how to do the equivalent in cmake.

I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cmake, you list all kinds of source files used to build the program in `add_executable` or `add_library`, and it figures the rest by itself. You'd put the `shaders.qrc` in the same place you put the rest of the source files - i.e. within `add_executable`.

See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-get-started.html) for an introduction. You definitely need the `set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)` line, so that cmake knows to take care of `.qrc` files as otherwise it'd just ignore them.